# "Ich weiss, dass du die Leidenschaft alles zu kontrollieren hast." — is it correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Seems to me that I just translated it from English literally.
P.S. Please, disregard the vocabulary I used. In this case the only thing that matters for me is that "zu kontrollieren".

Comment: First, provide at least the original English sentence. We can't tell if you translated literally otherwise. Second and more importantly, proofreading questions are off topic. Make sure your question is addressing an actual issue.

Comment: Original sentence? Does it matter, if the sentence (According to the only answer below this quesiton) is gramatically wrong? You know, you shouldn't have bothered writing all this stuff. By the answer I know now how to say it right, an by giant beige box (Which you couldn't help knowing that I would notice) I know, that this questions are not to be asked in this site. Thanks.

Comment: For the narrower question if the grammatical structure of the sentence is acceptable, the orginal sentence is not necessarily necessary. However, there is quite a probability that your translation has issues in terms of selecting the right words (depending on context of course); and then, selection of words can also impact syntax. So, asking you to publish your original sentence was actually good advice.

Comment: Thank you, I know it :) What I meant was, there was quite obvious what I wanted to know. In English it would be "I know that you have a passion to control everything". And in german (As I know now) it's different. That's it. Moreover, I have asked to DISREGARD the vocabulary since I knew, what I was doing) Or should I beg for it?) Sorry, if I sounded rude, I didn't mean it.

Comment: Hm... yes... right... indeed you asked to disregard vocabulary. Somehow I involuntarily disregarded that request for disregard.

Comment: These things happen :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be: "Ich weiss, dass du die Leidenschaft hast, alles zu kontrollieren." The commas are important.

Comment: However *Leidenschaft* in this context sounds, at least, unusual.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I think it deepens on the context *in which it is said*. I can imaginate that e.g. a men says it to his overly dominant wife in the case she yet again toke control over a situation without that she spoke about it with him while it would be expected by him in very that situation. A try to speak very open and direct while giving it a nice spin to make it not sound too reproachful.

Comment: Hey, guys, it's way more simple than you think) Actually, you made me doubt about my vocabulary in English so I double-checked it. I asked you all to DISREGARD the vocabulary) Ignore the words. Pay attention only to grammar) I'm a begginer - the only thing that matters for me is grammar. Vocabulary can be basically just ignored that early. That's all my opinion. I learn languages like that. It actually had quite a lot of success with my english, so.. thank you anyway, have a nice day)

Comment: If acceptable syntax is the only topic here, there are more options: **"Ich weiß dass du die Leidenschaft, alles zu kontrollieren, hast"** is technically also possible (although you would hardly find this sentence in the wild). More examples: **"Ich weiß, dass du Leidenschaft, alles zu kontrollieren, und eine Abneigung, anderen ihre Freiheit zu lassen, hast.** Or: **"Ich weiß, dass du die Leidenschaft hast, alles zu kontrollieren, und eine Abneigung, anderen ihre Freiheit zu lassen."** Mind the commas!